# Loopback: How to restrict access to some fields of a model

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

How do you restrict write/read access to some fields of a model?

For example, I have a model with fields 
`firstname`, `lastname`, `street`,...

And some fields that are responsible for relations with other models
`ownerId`,...

I would like to give write/read access for some fields e.g. `firstname`, but not for other fields like `ownerId`. How do I do this?

I tried marking the field `ownerId` as hidden in the model.json file

```
{
  ...,
  "hidden": ["ownerId"],
  ...
}
```

This hides the field from the json that is returned, like specified in the documentation, but it is still possible the change the fields using a PUT request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a look here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/531

You may want to check this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-ds-readonly-mixin

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope readOnly properties are implemented soon. In the meantime the package will have to do.